# Hibernate-search 5.0 spatial - Not sure it is storing lat/lon in hashes

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm using  [Hibernate-Search 5.2](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#spatial), and trying to index coordinates using spatial hashes. I am using this with PostgreSQL 9.4.

I have followed the directions, and everything works right (searches return results), but when I look at the values stored for latitude and longitude in pgAdmin, I see the actual numerical values rather than hashes as I would have expected.

Is this normal behavior or am I, in fact, not storing the values as hashes as I originally intended?

Here is a sample of my class:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Spatial(spatialMode = SpatialMode.HASH, name = "entityLocation")
@Table
public class RatedEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long entityId;

    private String name;
    private String entityType;
    private String address;
    private String city;

    @Column(length = 2)
    private String state;

    @Latitude(of = "entityLocation")
    @Column
    private Double latitude;

    @Longitude(of = "entityLocation")
    @Column
    private Double longitude;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate Search synchronizes your database-stored entities with an Apache Lucene index.

This index is not stored in the relational database, so using *pgAdmin* (or other SQL terminals) is not the right tool to inspect the content of the index, as you're effectively using NoSQL technology combined with the relational database.

The Lucene index is typically stored on filesystem, the location being controlled by Hibernate configuration properties such as:

```
hibernate.search.default.directory_provider = filesystem
hibernate.search.default.indexBase = /usr/lucene/indexes
```

See also [Directory Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.5/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-configuration-directory) in the reference documentation.

To open these high performance binary encoded indexes you might want to use a tool like [Luke](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke), or the [Eclipse tooling for Hibernate Search](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/hibernate-search-plugin)

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!